# Can't get profile details of user that have privacy on my API instagram PHP

Tags: php, api, instagram

this is my very first post here, am so sorry if my english too bad, I've got some problem about getting user details, iam tryied to get user details of member that have private account in Instagram who i followed on instagram, its mean i can see the details of their profile on mobile phone (instagram app) but it running error in my API, anyone can help me?

this is the error message

```
stdClass Object ( [meta] => stdClass Object ( [error_type] => APINotAllowedError [code] => 400 [error_message] => you cannot view this resource ) )
```

I need help, thanks before :D

Comment: It seems like it's not possible. I just tried it here [link](https://apigee.com/console/instagram) but got the same APINotAllowedError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use user search API, you will get user information like full_name, id, bio, website and profile_picture even if user is private:

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=USERNAME`

This API will return few user results, match the one with your USERNAME and get the user details.