# Getting "APINotAllowedError" when requesting medias on a private profil, even with all scopes allowed

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm using the PHP Instagram API https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API

I would like to retrieve the feed of a user, even if he has a private profil.

First, I'm generating the url with all the scopes granted

```
$instagram->getLoginUrl(array('basic','likes', 'relationships', 'comments'));
```

Then, once the user approved the application, I try to retrieve his feed

```
// Grab OAuth callback code
$code = $_GET['code'];

$data = $instagram->getOAuthToken($code);

// Set token
$instagram->setAccessToken($data->access_token); 


// get medias
$medias = $instagram->getUserMedia($data->user->id, -1);
```

I get an APINotAllowedError error

```
object(stdClass)#5 (1) {
  ["meta"]=>
  object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
    ["error_type"]=>
    string(18) "APINotAllowedError"
    ["code"]=>
    int(400)
    ["error_message"]=>
    string(29) "you cannot view this resource"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much!

**UPDATE AND FIX**

Ok actually it comes from the PHP library, the current getUserMedia() fails because it doesn't use the access_token provided...

Here is the correct method

```
public function getUserMedia($id = 'self', $limit = 0) {
    return $this->_makeCall('users/' . $id . '/media/recent', true, array('count' => $limit));
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: See if these help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970001/cant-get-profile-details-of-user-that-have-privacy-on-my-api-instagram-php,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280551/instagram-access-token-to-retrieve-any-user-feed

Comment: Post your update as an answer

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: After June 1, 2016. You can no longer access a private profile via API even if you are following/approved by that user. You will get error `APINotAllowedError`. Only way to view private profile if you are following is by using instagram app or instagram.com.

But if your profile is private, you can access it via API using your `access_token`

---

You cannot access a profile if user is private. This is the right response when accessing a private user with a access_token that does not have access to the user

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"APINotAllowedError","code":400,"error_message":"you cannot view this resource"}}
```

You can get the correct response only if you access the API with a user's access_token that has been allowed to access the user.