# can i see all my friends media after switch client from sandbox to live mod?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

first, sorry for my poor english.
i'm new in instagram api. 
when i try to get user media of my friends in sendbox mode, only non private accounts is available and for private account i'll face to this error.

```
"stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [error_type] => APINotAllowedError
            [code] => 400
            [error_message] => you cannot view this resource
        )

)"
```

now i want to know after switching to live mode can i see all media of this friend.
thanks.

Comment: there's no one else to help ??? !!!!!!!

Comment: i'm only want to know after switch to live mode can i see private (my friends account - this user is my follwer and i'm follow him) acount media.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701131/getting-apinotallowederror-when-requesting-medias-on-a-private-profil-even-wi

Comment: in some applications like 'instafollow' i can see my friends basic info and media even his account is private. what about that ??!!

Answer (score 0):

NO, Instagram API no longer allows accessing private users, even if are following and allowed access by other users.

Only way to access your private friend's media is using instagram.com or instagram app.

Comment: thank you sir. but in some applications like 'instafollow' i can see my friends basic info and media. what about that ??!! -and thank you again for answer.

Comment: you can see info if your friend profile is public, API does not allow private profile, did u give your password to instafollow?

Comment: thanks again for answer . yes i give my password to instafollow and when i login in to app i can see list of my follower and following. after click on each of them i can see bio and media even that account is private . now i need to build an application like that for myself. i dont want to publish my app

Comment: then they may not be using API, did it rediect to instagram.com page and u logged in or did instafollow UI have option to enter username/password ?

Comment: no. no need to login in instagram login page. and no any redirection is happened.

Comment: then they may be storing your raw password and automating login and pulling data.